# What is the principle of browser adaptation? Does anyone know? I will be very grateful

Tags: javascript

Today, I encountered this problem in the interview and felt very confused. I hope someone can answer it. thank you very much.

Comment: principle (a fundamental truth or proposition that serves as the foundation for a system of belief or behaviour or for a chain of reasoning) browser adaptation (an evolutionary process whereby an entity becomes better able to live in its habitat or habitats).. essentially the meaning is long-winded version of what is PWA (progressive web app), interviewers love to be crypted and convolute standards to trip you up

Comment: They may also tried to ask about adaptive web design which means the web UI selects its layout according to the browser. This is not responsive design. This is like if it's a mobile browser, than the page is created from a completely different layout than the desktop version, it does not simply resize. The question is a bit cryptic, in my opinion they tried to ask if you know the difference between responsive vs adaptive design.